# Is there an annual limit to how much money can be sent to a grandson for higher education?

Tags: united-states, education

How can a grandfather send money to grandson(US citizen) for US higher education?

Is there a limit per year ?

Does grandson have to pay gift tax to US government?

What documents are needed by grandfather?

Comment: Grandson is a US citizen. How about the grandfather? If he's not in the US - where is he?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a limit per year ?

There isn't a limit on the the grandson, but there might be on the grandfather. The local laws will apply.

> Does grandson have to pay gift tax to US government?

The grandson as a US citizen will not have to pay any gift taxes.

The gift will have to be accounted for when the son or his parents fill out the financial aid forms. It can impact how much aid they qualify for. If there is no need for financial aid, then the gift will not be included in a education linked forms.

> What documents are needed by grandfather?

That depends on where the grandfather lives and what country they are a citizen of.

Note: if the grandfather lives in the US then they maybe able to increase the amount they give by sending the money directly to the school.

Comment: If the grandfather is **not** in the US then there may be additional reporting requirements